# How would you prove this theory of computation problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle, ramsey-theory

I have trouble proving the following statement, I'm supposed to do it for our theory of computation course but since I've been trying for days I'm looking for a hint :

> What is the smallest value of $n\ge 1$ such that the following is true? (Write down the value if there is one and provide a proof of correctness of your argument or present a counterexample.)  Let $S$ be a subset of $\{1,\ldots,n^2\}$ of cardinality exactly $n$. Then there are two disjoint and nonempty subsets of it whose elements sum up to the same value.  That is to say there are $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that (1) $\emptyset\ne S_1,S_2\subset S$, (2) $S_1\cap S_2 = \emptyset$ and (3) $\sum_{i\in S_1} i = \sum_{j\in S_2} j$.

([original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIa6n.png))

*Clarifications : We want it to work for all possible subset S*

So far, I tried with the Pigeonhole principle and with the fact that for (n+1) numbers we have (2n+1) more numbers in the set {1,2,...,(n+1)^2 } because I thought it would lead me somewhere with a proof by Induction but couldn't manage to do so.

I know there might be some missunderstanding with the statement so feel free to ask for clarifications and I'll edit in order to help you helping me :)

Thank you !

Comment: I notice that the smallest value of $n$ must be at least 7, since otherwise $S = \{1, 2, \ldots 2^{n-1}\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Wouldn't we get $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64\}$?

Comment: $64\notin\{1,\ldots,7^2\}$.

Comment: Oh, got ya, you mean it is a counterexample when $|S|\leq 6$. A counterexample when $S=7$ also exists. The conways Guy sequence produces $44,43,42,40,37,31,20$. It has also been proven that the all sets that are counterexamples of larger sizes have an element larger than $n^2$. The link in my answer provides the smalles such subsets,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets of $S$.  The maximum sum of one of them is $n^3-\frac 12n(n-1)$.  At $n=10$ there are more subsets than possible sums, so two of them must have the same sum.  That leaves (using MJD's comment) the range $7,8,9,10$ to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if there are two **distinct** subsets with the same sum, by removing the intersection you get two disjoint subsets with the same sum.

How many subsets of $S$ are there?  How many possible sums?  If there are more subsets than possible sums, Pigeonhole says there are two subsets with the same sum.  This will get you a bound on $n$, though more work may be required to get the lowest possible $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $8$. [Here](http://fks.sk/~kubus/doc/201012ssd.pdf) is the proof it is true for $8$ or $9$ and a sequence for $7$ is given. Although the [Conway Guy sequence](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=Conway+and+Guy+sequence&source=bl&ots=Tkjxg1DKpy&sig=s-MPgE_7n0KWfQqnNDAK_r5aaRQ&hl=es-419&sa=X&ei=KKfsVMQ90bCiBMXcgYgP&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Conway%20and%20Guy%20sequence&f=false) also works for length $7$.  [This link](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-12/S0002-9939-96-03653-2/S0002-9939-96-03653-2.pdf) is also very interesting, and it proves the conway-guy sequence works for all lengths (which had only been established up to $79$ previously)